# Did Austria-Hungary have to cede land to Italy after occupying Serbia, and was it because of article 7?

Tags: world-war-one, italy, austria-hungary

Article VII of The Triple Alliance, signed 1912, states the following:

> Austria-Hungary and Italy, having in mind only the maintenance, so far as possible, of the territorial status quo in the Orient, engage to use their influence to forestall any territorial modification which might be injurious to one or the other of the Powers signatory to the present Treaty.
>
> To this end, they shall communicate to one another all information of a nature to enlighten each other mutually concerning their own dispositions, as well as those of other Powers. However, if, in the course of events, the maintenance of the status quo in the regions of the Balkans or of the Ottoman coasts and islands in the Adriatic and in the Aegean Sea should become impossible, and if, whether in consequence of the action of a third Power or otherwise, Austria-Hungary or Italy should find themselves under the necessity of modifying it by a temporary or permanent occupation on their part, this occupation shall take place only after a previous agreement between the two Powers, based upon the principle of a reciprocal compensation for every advantage, territorial or other, which each of them might obtain beyond the present status quo, and giving satisfaction to the interests and well founded claims of the two Parties.

So, if I interpret this article correctly, A-H not only broke this article when not informing Italy about their idea to invade Serbia, they also had to provide "reciprocal compensation", in the form of land, to Italy, which was not the case. Did Italy use this to justify the London-agreement as well as opening a front against A-H? And was it a legitimate reason to in their turn break article I, which states that no alliances hostile to the member states should be taken a part of?

Comment: @Evargalo Hungary begins with a U in a few languages, such as German, Swedish, and Norwegian. Perhaps Felix is from a country where that's the spelling.

Comment: @Evargalo yeah sorry, Hungary is "Ungern" in Swedish and I got a bit confused